# React: proxy img src references to a specific folder/file system location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, proxy, anki

For some context, I'm trying to render CrowdAnki JSON files in React. All the HTML in the JSON file is formatted to have this problem, and all the cards are stored as HTML strings which I have to (somewhat dangerously) pass to the `react-contenteditable` component e.g. `<ContentEditable html={anki_field} />`.

Is it possible in React to proxy all `img src` calls specifically to a specific folder? In this specific case, all the images and media are located in a folder e.g. `public/deck/media/`, and all the `src` attributes directly reference the media file e.g. `<img src="media-file.jpg" />`, for a file `public/deck/media/media-file.jpg`.

For this specific instance I don't think adding a proxy to the `package.json` would work, as I still need to fetch the JSON file from e.g. `public/deck`. Otherwise, is there some way to change all the `img src` file paths post-rendering?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest using a proxy component instead of manipulating the img element: https://reactpatterns.com/#proxy-component -- that's a pretty safe pattern to manipulate img sources without too much overhead.

Comment: This seems like it would work great if I was able to manipulate the individual HTML elements inside the JSON strings; however I am looking for something more general that could be applied at the parent component, would this still work? I've updated my question to clarify the conundrum I am working with, if that helps.